# MS Excel function need to count a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently using a calculation to count the number of cells of interest within a range as follows:

```
=Meta!$B$6-COUNTIF(L5:R14,"*AAA*")-COUNTIF(L5:R14,"*BBB*")-COUNTIF(L5:R14,"*CCC*")-COUNTBLANK(L5:R14)
```

== total minus 'cells to ignore'

This calculation occurs 24 times in each sheet and there are dozens of sheets. So when I need to add more cell types to ignore I have to copy and paste the equation far too many times, which is a real chore.

So I'd like to encapsulate the logic in a single function with an API that I can use like this:

```
= myCountFunction(currentSheet, range)
```

or possibly

```
= myCountFunction(range)
```

if excel is knows that the range in question belongs to a specific sheet.

I would welcome your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a good example of the need to copy to multiple spreadsheets at the same time (I assume that the formula is in the same location in each sheet). Have a look at the following instructions from Office: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Enter-data-in-multiple-worksheets-at-the-same-time-6223d385-4c75-4dff-9881-67d17972a6c9

Comment: Good tip! That certainly speeds things up considerably.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vba Function like this :

```
Function myCountFunction(inputCell As range, inputRange As range)

    myCountFunction = inputCell.Value - Application.CountIf(inputRange, "*AAA*") - Application.CountIf(inputRange, "*BBB*") - Application.CountIf(inputRange, "*CCC*") - Application.CountBlank(inputRange)

End Function
```

Call function with : = myCountFunction(Meta!$B$6; L5:R14)

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's exactly what I was looking for. I can now encapsulate the logic in one place.